# Header border frame missing in fedora after update the software packages

Tags: linux, updates, window, fedora-14, automatic-update

After installing some Fedora software updates, I can no longer see the header frame in every window. Furthermore, I can't access any window frame after I open a new window frame.

How can I fix this? Can I remove all the updates I recently installed?

Note : After installing these update, when I reboot the system, I can see there are two version of Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have a window manager running. If restarting the desktop doesn't fix it then make sure (assuming that you're using the default Gnome desktop) that the `metacity` is still installed.